# Unable To Get Extensions and Updates of A Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I am using `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate` and yesterday got into a big trouble while using the **Extensions and Updates** from the **Tools** feature. I tried to install the **Web Essentials** package but in the search option, it didn't show up as follows:

[image: Extensions and Updates]

Then I downloaded it manually and when tried to install, it showed the following error message with log details: Is there any way to get rid of it or Do I have to install any other feature or something?

[image: Manual Download]

**Log Details**:

```
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - -------------------------------------------
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Initializing Install...
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Extension Details...
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Identifier      : 5fb7364d-2e8c-44a4-95eb-2a382e30fec8
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Name            : Web Essentials 2013.5
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Author          : Mads Kristensen
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Version         : 2.6.36
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Description     : Adds many useful features to Visual Studio for web developers. Requires VS2013 Update 4 or 5
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Locale          : en-US
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     MoreInfoURL     : http://vswebessentials.com/
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     InstalledByMSI  : False
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - 
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     Supported Products : 
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -             Version : [12.0.31101,13.0)
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - 
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM -     References      : 
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - 
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Searching for applicable products...
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
9/14/2017 12:46:56 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

**Note**: I've searched in google, mostly given on `Visual Studio Express` and it said, in some cases, doesn't support the extensions. Is it the same for `Visual Studio Ultimate`?

Comment: Does Visual Studio need an update? Check the updates that you have installed.

Comment: It asks for `Visual Studio 2013 Update 5` and an update for `nuget`. Right now, I updated the `nuget` but still the same.